Netlify.toml not working, can't find path (React.js)
I deployed my site using Netlify and I'm having issues with routing.
I made a website for a telegram bot, and the routing doesn't work there, I tried nolify.toml to use it but it didn't help either, how can I solve the problem?
I made a website for a telegram bot, and the routing doesn't work there, I tried nolify.toml to use it but it didn't help either, how can I solve the problem?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
